# What type of array is this and how to display this array

Tags: php, arrays

How to display this using php and what type of array is this please explain

```
Array
(
    [name] => Ajin
    [username] => ajin
    [password] => password
)
```

Comment: It's an associative [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and you can use `echo $myArray['name']` to echo the `name` element, etc

Answer (score 0):

It's an associative array. This is how you can define it:

```
$array = array('name' => 'Ajin', 'username' => 'ajin', 'password' => 'password');
```

And you can get that output with [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
print_r($array);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Ajin
    [username] => ajin
    [password] => password
)
```

You can read more about array in the [manual](http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You can for example iterate through the array using [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to display it:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This outputs:

```
name: Ajin
username: ajin
password: password
```

Or you can access individual values as `$array['name']`:

```
echo $array['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an associative array.

**Associative arrays** - Arrays with named keys. You can define as

$array = array( 
  'name' => 'Ajin',
  'username' => 'ajin',
  'password' => 'password'
);

And we can show the output like

print_r($array);

or you can use it as -

foreach ($array as $key => $index) {
  echo "\n key $key => $index";
}